# How to make a button on the side of a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I've made a base site and I'm wondering how i would turn the button I have currently into a button which is attached onto the right side of the site in a box where it pulls out from?

example of what I'm trying to describe [1]

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/kasjT.png

I know this part isn't associated with the title but how would i have the dark mode I've set up effect "Undiscovered Beauty" element?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dipiu/jqh36L9o/2/

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="uft-8">
    <title>.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid height100p banner" id="home">
      <div class="container h100">
        <di class="contentBox h100">
            <div>
                <h1>Undiscovered Beauty</h1>
                <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ac augue accumsan, tristique leo ac, commodo nulla. Nulla sem orci, dapibus sed porta sit amet, convallis id quam. Phasellus in tellus vitae ligula pulvinar luctus. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="toggle"> </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, liber adipisci necessitatibus cum te, sea in nisl utamur. Ea regione lobortis eos, ei vix nostrud diceret. Et per aliquam eligendi, cu officiis euripidis cum. Vel at vocibus tincidunt, pri ne cibo dolores nominavi, prima sententiae dissentiet cum ea. In his altera corrumpit.Case legere accusam at has, ne sit probatus iracundia. Odio essent interpretaris ei eum. At cum erant honestatis, est probo commodo ei. Pri id erat facilis mentitum, pro an prima disputando. In salutandi urbanitas vix, vis oblique scaevola et.<br><br>
        Nec etiam explicari dissentias te, latine saperet habemus in mea. Te usu admodum pericula, eum ipsum soleat forensibus ad. Quo eu graeco luptatum accusamus. Dolore aperiri no usu, ei cum liber dictas diceret. Virtute saperet invidunt quo ei, lorem liber repudiandae nam ex, an his oratio quodsi debitis.Cu meis dicam pericula nec, illum commune perfecto at eos, ei pri latine vivendum posidonium. Vel iuvaret democritum at, vel propriae accusata ad, his vivendum signiferumque te. Vim dicunt molestie te, te quo erant splendide. No vis reque suavitate forensibus, id mea deseruisse eloquentiam. In sea offendit menandri adipiscing, ad pro libris labore graeco.</p>

    </div>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position:fixed` property like that for fixe your button :

```css
.btn{
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Button</button>
```

For the dark theme, you could add `.dark` class name, and toggle on it, like that :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#changeTheme").click(function(){
    $("body").toggleClass("dark");
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: white;
}

.dark{
  background-color: black;
}

.dark .bloc{
  background-color: gray;
}

.dark .bloc p{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="light">
  <div class="bloc">
    <p>
      Hello world !<br/>
      <a href="#" id="changeTheme"> Change theme</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide your button, you can make something like this.

```js
let $settings = $("#settings");
let $settings__toggle = $("#settings__toggle");

$settings__toggle.on('click', function () {
    $settings.toggleClass("settings_open");
})
```

```css
.settings {
    top: 20%;
    left: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.settings.settings_open {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.settings .settings__toggle {
    right: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="settings" class="settings">
    <button id="settings__toggle" class="settings__toggle">
        Toggle settings
    </button>
    <div>
        Your Settings
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```